# Making my own coaxial hardline

Tags: rf, coax, coaxial

I need about 50mm of coax hardline. I don't have any at home, but I do have a lathe, some copper, and some teflon stock.

Can I make my own coax hardline on the lathe? According to my calculations, for a 1mm center conductor, and a dielectric constant of 2.02 (PTFE), the outer conductor should be about 3.27mm for 50 ohms impedance.

I have a 3.25mm drill which should be close enough.

Would this work?

EDIT:

It's for building this antenna:

[image]

The antenna is simply a turnstile antenna, for 1.7ghz. hardline is used for support.

Comment: Try it. (Copper machines oddly. I have heard that the best lubricant/coolant for it is, oddly, milk).

Comment: @BrianDrummond so you think it's reasonable? i don't see why it wouldn't work but just wanting to make sure it's a sane idea.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Could "milk" have been a slight mistranslation of emulsified oil? Otherwise, the lathe might start smelling bad after a day or two.

Comment: That's a different matter. I think it's way more work than is worthwhile.

Comment: That was asked (not by me) and the oldtimer replied no, actual milk. I can't personally vouch for it. Clean the lathe afterwards...

Comment: @BrianDrummond I found a reference: *The Machinist's Bedside Reader* by Guy Lautard is mentioned in [Machining copper](https://www.practicalmachinist.com/vb/general-archive/machining-copper-78223/) on PracticalMachinist.com as containing the suggestion to use milk.

Comment: See also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rec.crafts.metalworking/qdIf_ZKMLkQ (about 8 messages down) ... another reference to Lautard.

Comment: i don't know anything about coax hardlines, but this popped into my head ... could you strip the outer jacket from a coax cable and insert the dielectric and center core into an appropriately sized copper pipe?

Comment: What frequency is this? And I am rather OK with copper, but how you will form teflon pieces?

Comment: @fraxinus 1.7ghz. and teflon is machinable. if not, I could use another plastic, as long as i find its dielectric constant.

Comment: @jsotola i was thinking of that. the problem is I only have the "melty" stuff. teflon has the advantage of not melting when you solder it.

Comment: I am sure there are coaxial cables w/ PTFE insulation. Just check tne disassembled stuff around you.

Comment: could you add teflon "ends"?

Comment: Id' honestly just go with coaxial cable as waveguide, and for mechanical support, use styrofoam, or some other foam that isn't especially conductive.